# Map each value of an array to a given function to return a new array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code below throws the following exeption:

> Uncaught TypeError: someFunction(...) is not a function

What is causing this exception to be thrown?

```js
map = function (someList, someFunction){
    var result =[];
    for (x = 0; x < someList.length; x++ ){
        result.push(someFunction(someList[x])());
    }
    return result;
};

map([1,2,3,4], function(num){
    return num * 10;
});
```

Comment: Thank's everyone! I just write an extra parentheses after someFunction "()".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line

```
result.push(someFunction(someList[x])());
                                     ^^
```

This extra parentheses are redundant. You are already calling the function `someFunction` by saying `someFunction(someList[x])`. By adding these extra parentheses, you are basically trying to call the return value of `someFunction(someList[x])`, which is a number here, not a function.